# Qual o meu erro nesse codigo?

Tags: javascript, array, return

Olá, estou começando a estudar a linguagem JS e empaquei aqui, não sei qual meu erro, alguém poderia me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PAGINA</title>
  </head>
  <body>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculaRetangulo(b,h) {
      var area = (b*h);
      var perimetro = (b+h)*2;
      return[area,perimetro];
    };
  </script>

<button type="button" onclick=" var resposta = calculaRetangulo(5,10); alert("AREA: " + resultado[0]); alert("Perimetro" + resultado[1])">EXECUTAR</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar aspas duplas em `alert()`, use aspas simples. Você já está usando as aspas duplas ao redor do código, então quando você incluiu no alerta as aspas se abrem e fecham diversas vezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca use aspas duplas (`"`) dentro de aspas duplas, ou aspas simples (`'`) dentro de aspas simples, ou se for necessário fazer isso, você terá que usar uma técnica para escapar a string usando algo do tipo `\string para escapar\`, caso contrario você estará fechando o atributo, se abrir o console do navegador pode ver como ele lê o trecho do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando na verdade era pra ter sido lido assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alem disso você confundiu a variável resposta com a variável resultado que nem existia.

O Código correto poderia ser assim

```js
function calculaRetangulo(b, h) {
  var area = (b * h);
  var perimetro = (b + h) * 2;
  return [area, perimetro];
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="var resposta = calculaRetangulo(5,10); alert('AREA: '+resposta[0]); alert('Perimetro: '+resposta[1])">EXECUTAR</button>
```

Comment: Contunia mesma coisa, console aponta isso -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: calma vou ver aqui e jájá te dou a resposta

Comment: Leone, inclua a explicação do que o seu código faz e qual a diferença dele pro que está na pergunta. Assim fica fácil pra quem achar essa resposta depois.

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisada sobre o que é parseInt

Comment: O código correto é esse, me enganei em relação ao parseInt()

Comment: Você além das aspas, confundiu resposta com resultado

Comment: Uhum, mais agora entendi quais foram meus erros, vlw pela ajuda

Comment: Por favor retribua minha ajuda marcando minha resposta como a correta clicando no ícone em forma de v verde ao lado da resposta

Comment: Apesar de o código resolver o problema, a resposta em nada explica o que estava errado no código do AP, por isso dei -1, se explicar o erro eu retiro o voto -1 =)

Comment: estava nos comentários vou passar para a resposta obg pelo esclarecimento @MarceloBoni

Comment: Acrescentei meus dois cents a sua resposta, pode reverter para o estado anterior caso sinta necessidade

Answer (score 1):

Você esta usando aspas duplas para iniciar o `onClick()` e dentro do próprio `onClick()` você também esta usando aspas duplas que é o que esta gerando este erro, quando você faz `onClick="...` e coloca outra aspas duplas logo em seguida o que é interpretado é que o `onClick()` já terminou por exemplo:

```
<button onClick="alert("oi")">click</button>
                      /\ - o onClick termina aqui
```

O método correto seria:

```
<button onClick="alert('oi')">click</button>
                      /\ aspas simples
```

Leve isso sempre como uma regra, se você começar com aspas duplas use aspas simples dentro delas e virse e versa.

Comment: Entendi... Vlw pela ajuda

Comment: Se a resposta está correta por favor marque como resolvido (o sinal de "v" ao lado esquerdo)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo done.

Comment: agora sim, bem melhor, +1